# What is this comma? Is it necessary?

Tags: punctuation, participle-clauses

He saw no **other** way to stop the killing but by forcing the Germans and Japanese to change their militaristic philosophy. This idea of changing a nation’s philosophy was intimately linked to FDR’s unconditional surrender policy. In his mind he seemed to envision unconditional surrender as making Germany and Japan tabulae **rasae, swept** bare of all their bad ideas, awaiting American infusion of good ideas.

Is this comma necessary? I don't think so. The reason is that swept is best interpretred to be restrictive in its modification of "tabulae rasae." like, "make him a singer who will appeal to the common masses"

Additionally, what is this other? I think it is no less redundant, since we have "but" to mean except than the other of "I have no other choice to do..." is.

Comment: @snailboat There is enough context to answer the question, so why does the source matter in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The *swept* clause is set off in commas because it is nonrestrictive: the author is not restricting his reference to a particular subset of tabulae rasae , he is explaining what he means by the term *tabula rasa*.

The equivalent in your counterexample would be something like

> ... make him a popular singer, appealing to the common masses ...

where the *appealing* clause glosses the term *popular singer*: not a singer of the sort of songs called 'popular music', but (as you say) 'a singer who will appeal &c'.

Note, by the way, that the *awaiting* clause might be restrictive: if you remove the parenthetical *swept* clause and its parenthesizing commas you are left with

> tabulae rasae awaiting American infusion of good ideas.

But it might equally be regarded as a second nonrestrictive clause, paralleling the first; and the good ideas/bad ideas contrast lends weight to that reading.

I agree with your second point: it should be either *no other way **than forcing** the Germans* or *no way **but** forcing the Germans*. But it is a very minor point of style which few would notice.

Comment: I think awaiting is like this, "They are turned into tabulae rasae, awaiting..." like, "The train left NY, arriving in SFC three days later."

Comment: @user8153 I agree, for the reasons I have given; but it might also be like "The hotel limo will meet passengers arriving in SFC."

Answer (score 1):

The "swept bare of all their bad ideas" is set apart (with commas) because it's a **subordinate clause**. (So is the "awaiting" one after it.) It is not *necessary* to the previous statement, about making them *tabulae rasae*, but it provides further information.

The first comma *could* be left out, but it would subtly change the emphasis of the sentence. On a stylistic note, it would also make the sentence feel "cluttered": too much being said without a pause.

As for "other", it is (again) not required. You're right, the "but" makes the "other" unnecessary, but "no **other** way but" is still the usual phrasing. I think it's because it tells the reader what to expect. As soon as you read "other", you know he's got one idea how to stop the killing. If it wasn't there, the reader might think (at first) that he's got *no* idea how to stop the killing. After getting to the "but", and realising that this interpretation was wrong, the reader would have to pause to make a quick mental adjustment.

That's my theory, anyway.